# Except function doesn't work on a list that I got from xml file

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, except

I am trying to use IEnumerable.Except function in c# 4.0 to get the difference between two lists like this:

```
//Function to get only available rooms out of all rooms of the hotel...
public IEnumerable<Room> GetAvailableRooms(DateTime arrival, DateTime leaving)
        {
                //.....
                foreach (Room value in v)
                    room_list.Add(value);
                return (dal.GetAllRooms()).Except(room_list);                
        }
```

but the function doesn't work - it doesn't remove the items of room_list.

(I checked in debugging and room_list contains the desired values)

dal.GetAllRooms is a functions that gets all rooms from xml file in Data Access Layer.

I am sure that the problem is about xml because when I use my DAL implemention with lists (not xml) the same exact function works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation given by Daniel is correct when you are checking for equality. But in order to use **Except()** for a custom class you need to override the **GetHashCode()** method for your custom class. See below code snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ObservableCollection<A> one = new ObservableCollection<A>();
        ObservableCollection<A> two = new ObservableCollection<A>();

        one.Add(new A()
        {
            number = 1,
            name = "A"
        });

        one.Add(new A()
        {
            number = 2,
            name = "B"
        });

        two.Add(new A()
        {
            number = 1,
            name = "A"
        });


        ObservableCollection<A> three = new ObservableCollection<A>(one.Except(two));

    }
}

class A : IEquatable<A>
{
    public int number;
    public string name;

    public bool Equals(A other)
    {
        return (number == other.number && name == other.name);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Get the hash code for the Textual field if it is not null.

        int hashnumber = number == null ? 0 : number.GetHashCode();



        // Get the hash code for the Digital field.

        int hashname = name.GetHashCode();



        // Calculate the hash code for the object.

        return hashnumber ^ hashname;

    }
}
```

Here **three** will have the value as {2,"B"}.

Answer (score 1):

Do you override `Object.Equals` in `Room`? Or do you implement [`IEquatable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)? If not, `Except` checks whether the references are the same and they are not, even if all values inside the instances are the same.

Example:

```
class Room
{
    public Room(int roomNumber) { RoomNumber = roomNumber; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
}

class Room2
{
    public Room2(int roomNumber) { RoomNumber = roomNumber; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var otherRoom = other as Room2;
        if(otherRoom == null)
            return false;

        return roomNumber == otherRoom.RoomNumber
    }
}


var room1a = new Room(404);
var room1b = new Room(404);

var room2a = new Room2(405);
var room2b = new Room2(405);

Assert.False(object.Equals(room1a, room1b));
Assert.True(object.Equals(room2a, room2b));
```

Comment: I will try, but I don't think it matters because it works when I use my list implemention of dal.